# Vim ESLint not approved or denied yet

Tags: eslint, coc.nvim, neovim

I am new to vim and stumble across a problem.
I was working on another TS project and ESlint worked fine and I even enable format on save.
But upon changing the project, the linter stopped working and I no longer have the format on save or any type of help, any one knows how to solve this?

I am using Coc's coc-eslint

I have all the modules installed and the linter works fine on my vscode ...

[Here is a print of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0f4e.png)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out the fix is simple!
Type

```
:CocCommand eslint.showOutputChannel
```

And accept it!